# Conduct ItemSearchBasic for items with particular price level?

Tags: soap, netsuite

I'm using an iPaaS which leverages NetSuite's SOAP web services to provide RESTlike read/write access to NetSuite account data. These endpoints support searches, but from what I can tell in the NetSuite SOAP Web Services Usage Log, they are only `_____SearchBasic`. Example partial request body:

```xml
    ...
    <soapenv:Body>
        <search xmlns="urn:messages_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <searchRecord xsi:type="ns10:ItemSearch" xmlns:ns10="urn:accounting_2019_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <ns10:basic xsi:type="ns11:ItemSearchBasic" xmlns:ns11="urn:common_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    // additional search parameter(s) here?
                    <ns11:type xsi:type="ns13:SearchEnumMultiSelectField" operator="anyOf" xmlns:ns13="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_assembly</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_description</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_discount</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_downloadItem</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_giftCertificateItem</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_inventoryItem</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_itemGroup</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_kit</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_markup</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_nonInventoryItem</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_otherCharge</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_payment</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_service</ns13:searchValue>
                        <ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_subtotal</ns13:searchValue>
                    </ns11:type>
                </ns10:basic>
            </searchRecord>
        </search>
    </soapenv:Body>
    ...
```

I need to search for items in NetSuite that belong to a particular price level. I've look at the [`ItemSearchBasic` schema](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/search/itemsearchbasic.html) and can't find quite what I need. For instance, I can search for items that have a specific `price`, and the items that are returned contain a `pricingMatrix` with `pricing` objects with a `priceLevel`, but I can't seem to search for a `priceLevel` with an `ItemSearchBasic`. Example partial response with the fields I care about:

```xml
                ...
                <platformCore:recordList>
                    <platformCore:record xsi:type="listAcct:InventoryItem" externalId="1810" internalId="642" xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2019_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                        ...
                        <listAcct:isInactive>false</listAcct:isInactive>
                        <listAcct:currency>5</listAcct:currency>
                        <listAcct:pricingMatrix>
                            <listAcct:pricing>
                                <listAcct:currency internalId="1">
                                    <platformCore:name>USA</platformCore:name>
                                </listAcct:currency>
                                <listAcct:priceLevel internalId="1">
                                    <platformCore:name>Retail/Web</platformCore:name>
                                </listAcct:priceLevel>
                                <listAcct:priceList>
                                    <listAcct:price>
                                        <listAcct:value>12.0</listAcct:value>
                                    </listAcct:price>
                                </listAcct:priceList>
                            </listAcct:pricing>
                            ...
```

In summary, my question is two-fold:

1. How can I search for items belonging to a particular price level with an `ItemBasicSearch`?
2. If that's not possible, how can I search for items belonging to a particular price level using the NetSuite SOAP web services?

Alternatively, I believe I could get the data I need by retrieving items that exist at a particular location (as in, have a quantity of zero or more at a particular location). Is there a way to query for that within an `ItemBasicSearch`?

Forgive me if I'm missing something or using the wrong terminology. I'm new to both NetSuite and SOAP.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Itemsearchadvanced.

soapenv:Body


<ns10:basic xsi:type="ns11:ItemSearchAdvanced" xmlns:ns11="urn:common_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
// additional search parameter(s) here?
<ns11:type xsi:type="ns13:SearchEnumMultiSelectField" operator="anyOf" xmlns:ns13="urn:core_2019_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_assembly</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_description</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_discount</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_downloadItem</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_giftCertificateItem</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_inventoryItem</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_itemGroup</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_kit</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_markup</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_nonInventoryItem</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_otherCharge</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_payment</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_service</ns13:searchValue>
<ns13:searchValue xsi:type="xsd:string">_subtotal</ns13:searchValue>
</ns11:type>
</ns10:basic>


</soapenv:Body>

Comment: I have the same question as OP and am not seeing how this answers the question.